# $F$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_p$ for some prime number $p$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Suppose $F$ is a field and there is a ring homomorphism from $\Bbb Z$ onto $F$. Then show that $F$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_p$ for some prime number $p$.

I am facing difficulty to do the proof. I think that we have to make a map so that the kernel of the homomorphism goes to class $0$ of $\Bbb Z_p$.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** If $\varphi : \mathbb{Z} \to F$ is a homomorphism onto $F$, then $\mathbb{Z}/\ker \varphi \cong F$. But if $\mathbb{Z}/\ker \varphi \cong F$ is a field, what can you say about the ideal $\ker \varphi$ in $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: kernels are of the form $n \Bbb Z$. But $ℤ/nℤ$ is a field if and only if $n$ is prime.